# Order Facebook Places results by distance

Tags: facebook, location, facebook-fql

Does anyone know how to order Facebook places by distance from a search location? Note that I don't want to order results in my client app. I want the Facebook server to provide me with ordered results to facilitate pagination. I always want to append places from subsequent queries to the end of my array.

This does not seem possible using the graph API query such as:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&.... because there is no way to tell Facebook to order the results. The nearest place may be last in the list of returned results.

I have been trying to replicate the above query using `FQL` but have a problem in that the name & description fields in the Facebook place table are not indexable. FQL such as:

```sql
SELECT 
  page_id, name, display_subtext, description, 
  distance(latitude, longitude, "37.76", "-122.427"), checkin_count 
FROM place 
WHERE ((distance(latitude, longitude, "37.76", "-122.427") < 25000) 
  AND (strpos(lower(name), "coffee") >= 0 
  OR strpos(lower(description), "coffee") >= 0))
ORDER BY distance(latitude, longitude, "37.76", "-122.427") ASC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Problem with this is that the fields `name` and `description` are not indexable in the place table. This means that not all the results are returned by the FQL, there are many missing results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like it's possible using this FQL. The `contains` function seems to work the same as the `q=` Graph API param. Here's your example using `contains`

```sql
SELECT page_id, name, description, latitude, longitude, checkin_count, distance(latitude, longitude, "37.76", "-122.427")
FROM place
WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "37.76", "-122.427") < 1000
AND CONTAINS("coffee")
ORDER BY distance(latitude, longitude, "37.76", "-122.427")
LIMIT 20
```