# How can I get list of Facebook places inside bounds

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

I need to receive list of facebook places inside of given bounds (defined by NE and WS coordinates)

I call the following fql.query from javascript application:

```
 FB.api({
    method: "fql.query",

    query: "SELECT name,description,geometry,latitude,longitude,checkin_count,display_subtext FROM place WHERE latitude < '" + bounds.getNorthEast().lat() + "' and longitude < '" + bounds.getNorthEast().lng() + "' and latitude > '" +  bounds.getSouthWest().lat() + "' and longitude > '" +  bounds.getSouthWest().lng() +"'"
  },
  function(response) {
     /// 
 }
```

But I receive error 604

```
Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql
```

As far as I can see the only indexed column in `place` table http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/place/ is `page_id`. But I see no means to get this `page_id` from some other table.

Is there any (maybe more simple) way to receive facebook places within given bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it with fql, I was inspired by this answer:

[Facebook places: order results by distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166500/facebook-places-order-results-by-distance?rq=1)

I searched not within bounds, but within distance from central point, but using the fql.query language:

```
    FB.api({
      method: "fql.query",
      query: "SELECT page_id, name, description, latitude, longitude, checkin_count, distance(latitude, longitude, '"  + centerlat + "', '" + centerlon + "') FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, '" + centerlat + "', '" + centerlon + "') < '" + distance +"'" 
      },
      function(response) {

      });
```

And it does exactly what I need - gives me the list of places which I can use.

Answer (score 2):

You are right in that the FQL table can't be used since those columns are not indexed.
But you could try the Graph API call to Search for places within a particular location. 
Eg - https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=...
This comes from the Graph API doc here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: So to achieve my goal using javascript I need: 1. get Access_token, 2. request graph api. 3. listen for result and parse it. And the second question - is there any possibility to find places not within raduis, but within bounds? In docs its said that only radius param is suppported =(

Comment: I found a solution with fql (see my answer if interested. Anyway thank you for answer I'll +1 it =)