# Add location to newUploadPhotoRequest (Facebook) via Android app

Tags: android, facebook

Is there anyway to add location (by lat and long) to a facebook photo shared from Android app?

"this is the message" — in "location".

This is my code

```
 private void postPhoto() {
            Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), myBm, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    showPublishResult("photo_post", response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = request.getParameters(); 
            parameters.putString("message","test");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to directly set a *Latitude* and *Longitude* in a photo.

According to the Graph API reference for the photo the only geographical reference you can make to a photo is to a *place* `Page`

The Page, in it's turn has a `location` that has several fields, including the *Latitude* and *Longitude*.

Photo - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo

Page - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/

The easiest approach would be to create an FQL query to get the nearby places, but that I assume is not what you are looking for.
To know more about this query, you can check this other question: [How can I get list of Facebook places inside bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167258/how-can-i-get-list-of-facebook-places-inside-bounds)